# Query in Active record with an array of hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have the following model in Ruby

```
class Entity < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :account_type, presence: true
  validates :account_id, presence: true
end
```

and I have an array of hashes called accounts something like:

```
[{'account_id':44, 'account_type':'user'},..,{'account_id':44, 'account_type':'other'}, {'account_id':88,
'account_type':'another'}]
```

So I want a way to obtain all the entities that match with the elements of the accounts array (account_id and
account_type both at same time).

I tried using this code:

```
entities = []
accounts.each do |account|
    entities << Entity.where(account_id: ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(account)['account_id'])
    .where(account_type: ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(account)['account_type'])
end
```

But there is a way to do it more efficient ??

Comment: Since you want a record to match both attributes at the same time, then I can't think of a better way. However there may be a better way to accomplish whatever you are trying to do. Maybe there is an issue with the logic you followed that brought you to the need of that query and not the query itself.

Comment: Do you need to cast as `HashWithIndifferentAccess`, if you are only accessing by string? The two `where` clauses look like they could be combined into `where(account_id: account['account_id'], account_type: account['account_type])`, or possibly `where(account)` if you trust the attributes. You could also use `Entity.select('id, name').where()` to reduce the number of fields pulled if you don't need them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given this:

```
[{'account_id':44, 'account_type':'user'}, {'account_id':44, 'account_type':'other'}, ... ]
```

the SQL you want is:

```
select ...
where account_id = 44 and account_type = 'user'
   or account_id = 44 and account_type = 'other'
   or ...
```

Note that SQL's operator precedence makes that the same as:

```
select ...
where (account_id = 44 and account_type = 'user')
   or (account_id = 44 and account_type = 'other')
   or ...
```

You can build a query like that using ActiveRecord but it is a little cumbersome due to the way [`#or`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-or) works:

```
accounts = your_array_of_hashes
entities = accounts.inject(Entity.none) { |memo, h| memo.or(Entity.where(h)) }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using rails 5 you could try `or`. Something like this

```
entities = Entity.none
items.each do |item|
  entities = entities.or(Entity.where(item))
end
```

This is just one SQL query but if the array is big I don't know how this works.

Answer (score 0):

If i got your problem, this should solve it:

```
entities = accounts.map { |acc| Entity.where(account_id: acc['account_id'], account_type: acc['account_type']) }
```

Let me explain what is happening:

- first, the method `map` returns an array will all the entries that dit match with anything at the database
- the `map` is interating through the accounts array, just like the `each`, which means it will bring the data at accounts to the `where` query
- a `comma` between `where` conditions also works for comparisons, unless you are doing an `or`, in the case i suppose you can use this syntax: `where('account_id = :id or account_type = :type', id: acc['account_id'], type: acc['account_type'])`